# Data from two data frames in one plot (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I've got two data frames in R, both of the same structure - with columns named: `Year, Age, Gender and Value1`.

What I'd like to do, is to plot (as points) *Value1* (on Y axis) against *Year* (on X axis), for a particular gender and age. The plot should consists of points from both data frames (with legend indicating which points are from which data frame).

What I've done is:

```
attach(df1)
plot(Value1[Gender=="Female" & Age==30] ~ Year[Gender=="Female" & Age==30])
```

which creates the plot with points from one data frame. The question is, how to add the points from the second data frame to the same plot, and how to create proper legend? I tried few combinations of the `points()` formula, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a reproducable example it is not very easy to help. Assuming your data frames are called df1,df2 you can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df1$frame="1"
df2$frame="2"
df=rbind(df1,df2)
df<-filter(df,Gender=="Female"&Age==30)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Year,y=Value1,col=frame))+geom_point()
```